# Refresing the state after logging in, in order to display content depending on user roles in Angular JS & ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

In my angular app, when a user visits the "home" state (I am using ui-router), he gets a welcome message.

When pressing a login button, a overlay appears and the user can authenticate.

Upon a successful authentication, I want to do some API calls and display stuff on the template.

All of this in code, looks like this:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "app/sections/home/homeTpl.html",
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });
}])

.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'Session', 'MoviesService', function ($scope, Session, MoviesService) {
    if (Session.getUserRole() === 'USER') {
        // Add a movie.
        $scope.newMovie = {
            name: 'I am the new movie'
        };
        MoviesService.save($scope.newMovie);
    }
}])
```

When the users authenticates, the controller check's the user role and if he is a "USER" do stuff....

Now, in order for everything to work, I need Angular ui-router to refresh the state, after logging in:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, {}, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```

While it works, I am not sure this is the way to go regarding best practices...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you really need notify but you can use `$state.reload` that an alias for transitionTo. [$state doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

After I think your are right, I do the same for my app.

Comment: I see Mathieu, so you believe the logic is ok?

Comment: Yes because you need to refresh your controller because in your context you are now logged

Comment: Another way was to setup watches on every component in the view - but it seems resource costly -- I could watch the userRole for changes

Comment: watches are consuming a lot of resources so a refresh is for me the best. If you look at SPA website you always have a refresh when you login and logout